# Pros/cons to using char for small integers in C

Tags: c, performance, char, int

Is there any disadvantage to using `char` for small integers in C? Are there any advantages other than the occupancy/memory benefit?

In particular, is the processor likely to cope with integer arithmetic on a `char` better or worse than it would on a (`long`/`short`) `int`?

I know this will be processor/system/compiler specific, but I'm hoping for an answer in the general case, or, at least, the general case for 32-bit Windows and Solaris, being the systems I'm currently working on. I'm also assuming that things like overflow/wraparound issues have already been dealt with.

Update: Visual Studio 6.0 doesn't actually have `stdint.h` as suggested by Christoph. A little benchmarking on Windows (VS 6.0, debug build, 32-bit) with a handful of stacked loops gives `int` and `long` as providing similar performance, which is about twice as fast as `char`. Running the same test on Linux with gcc similarly pegs `int` and `long` as similar, and both faster than `char`, although the difference is less pronounced.

As a side note, I've not spent much time looking, but [the first implementation of `stdint.h` for VS 6.0 I found](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h) (via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stdint.h&oldid=335927920)) defines `uint_fast8_t` as `unsigned char`, despite this seeming to be slower in my tests at least. Thus, the moral of the story, as Christoph rightly suggested: always benchmark!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C99 added so-called 'fastest' minimum-width integer types to solve this problem. For the range you're interested in, the types would be `int_fast8_t` and `uint_fast8_t`, which can be found in `stdint.h`.

Keep in mind that there might be no performance gain (the increase in memory consumption might even slow things down); as always, benchmark! Don't optimize prematurely or solely on potentially flawed assumptions of what should work.

Comment: If you care about portability (like I do where I share code between embedded target and PC) don't use fast types to actually "store" anything (class members, struct members, etc.). Use fast types to iterate, access arrays or as a local cache variable.

Comment: @MaR: using fixed-sized integer types is not enough to guarantee that structures can be serialized and deserialized across architectures because of padding and byte order; as you'll therefore have to serialize structure members sequentially anyway, I don't think there's anything wrong with using fast types for member variables

Comment: @Christoph: well it's not only about serialization, but true - my statement was too strong. It should be rather 'be careful about it' as increased size can hit you hard in certain scenarios.

Comment: Benchmarking is certainly the moral of this story; I've just updated the question with the results of some benchmarking I've done. Notably, the stdint.h implementation I found for Visual Studio defines uint_fast8_t as something that is far from the fastest type in my tests.

Comment: A *major* gotcha with the stdint.h types is that there is for all practical purposes no guarantee of when math between signed and unsigned types will yield a signed or unsigned result (since that is determined by the sizes of the types and question, rather than the types used, and if one *knew* the sizes of the types in question one wouldn't have need of the types like `uint_fast8_t` in the first place).  For example, the sum of an `int32_t` and a `uint_fast8_t` might be a signed or unsigned 32-bit integer, and (on 8- or 16-bit machines) the product of two `uint8_fast8_t` values...

Comment: ...could be a 16-bit *signed* `int` which would be unable to hold results larger than 32767.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the first issue is that it's not defined by the C standard whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned - so the only range you can portably rely on is 0 to 127.

Other than that, in general `int` is supposed to be the type corresponding to the native word size of the architecture (but of course this isn't enforced by anything).  This would tend to be the type with the best arithmetic performance, but that's about all you can say.

Note that operands narrower than `int` are widened either to `int` or `unsigned int` during expression evaluation anyway.

Comment: yep, I've been told that a int has the size of a processor register, so if you use a char, the register will not be full but will still use  the same time to make basical operations be the register fully used or not.

Comment: In addition, int8_t and uint8_t would be better types to use than char.

Comment: @Aif: As far as I know, it takes even *more* time to do the up/down conversion.

Comment: I came across these 2: 
<http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/optimizingcandcppcode.htm#Prefer int over char and short> and <http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Performance_improving_features> but I don't consider either authoritative. Sorry, no hard proof, looks more like anecdotal.

Answer (score 3):

Another con I can think of is that (as far as I know) "modern" processors do all their math in "full" integers, generally 32 bits. So dealing with a `char` usually means pulling a single byte out of memory, filling up with 0's in transferring to a register, doing something with it and then squeezing only the least significant bits of the result back into memory. Especially if the `char` is not aligned on a handy boundary, this memory access takes a lot more work to accomplish.

Using `char` for `int` is really only useful when you have a *lot* of numbers (i.e. a large array) and you need to conserve space.

Comment: Chars require fewer cache line fills and fit better in cache.

Answer (score 3):

Arithmetic on chars will almost certainly actually performed using the same registers as arithmetic on ints. For example:

```
char c1 = 1;
char c2 = c1 + 2;
```

The addition compiles to the following with VC++:

```
00401030   movsx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-4]
00401034   add         eax,2
00401037   mov         byte ptr [ebp-0Ch],al
```

where eax is a 32-bit register.

There is therefore no adavantage for using chars over ints when it comes to arithmetic performance.

Comment: Yes, but isn't access to a byte slower because of alignment issues? The fact that the access is a single line of ASM doesn't mean there's not more microcode being executed. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: Guilty as charged on perhaps too much simplification on "filling in with 0's" and "squeezing into a byte". But I do believe something like this is happening, at *some* level.

Comment: I have no idea about the bus access times (which I think is the real issue) for modern processors, I'm afraid - I was answering the question about arithmetic performance.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, processors generally perform arithmetic on machine words. This means that when calculations on other types are performed, although the calculation itself will take the same length of time, depending on the available instruction set extra work may have to be done to read inputs and to coerce calculation results into the target type (e.g. sign-extending/zero-filling, shifting/masking to avoid unaligned memory accesses, etc).

This is why C defines types and operations as it does - the size of `int` is not mandated by the standard, allowing compiler authors to make it correspond to a machine word, and expression evaluation is defined to promote smaller integer types to `int`, greatly reducing the number of points at which results must be coerced to some target type.

Valid reasons to use `char` for storing integer values are when the space really matters that much (not as often as you might think), and when describing some external data format / protocol that you are marshalling data to / from. Expect uses of `char` to incur a slight loss of performance, especially on hardware such as Cell SPU where only machine word size memory accesses are available so accessing a char in memory requires several shifts and masks.

Answer (score 0):

The main con I would see is that your code is using a type that means one thing for values that mean something else -- e.g., there's a semantic problem which could be a maintenance problem. If you did it, I'd probably recommend typedefing it:

```
typedef char REALLYSHORT;
```

That way, A) It's clearer what you're doing, and B) You can change it easily (e.g., just the one place) if you run into trouble.

Do you have a *really good reason* not to use `int`?

Comment: Your semantic point is already used in the only place I've seen this implemented. And no, I have no good reason whatsoever, I'm just curious as to whether it makes a difference.